# Stop Duplicates From A List From A .txt File Python 3.6

Tags: python

I've made a program that identifies what is inside a text file, splits it into individual lines, and prints a `random.choice` from it. For example, when I run the program, it will print 3 lines of the text file, however there are duplicates. First of all, here is the text file:

```
Ball
Rock
Pen
```

And here is the code:

```
import random

lines = open(r"textfile.txt", "r").readlines()

line = lines[random.randint(0, 2)]
words = line.split()
choice = random.choice(words)
print(choice)

line = lines[random.randint(0, 2)]
words = line.split()
choice = random.choice(words)
print(choice)

line = lines[random.randint(0, 2)]
words = line.split()
choice = random.choice(words)
print(choice)
```

Right now, when I run the program I get an input similar to this:

```
Ball
Rock 
Rock
```

or

```
Rock
Rock
Pen
```

What I want to come out is all 3 lines, with no duplicates. For example:

```
Rock
Ball
Pen
```

My question is:
How can I get an output with all 3 outcomes in a random order each time, with no duplicates?

Comment: Use random.sample instead. So `choice = random.sample(words, 3)`. And then `print('\n'.join(choice))` for instance.

Comment: @AntonvBR Doing this, I get the error `ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative`

Comment: Ok I see now.. your file is separated with row breaks? I will show you in a moment

Comment: I am afk right now, so i cant show you but instead of calling randint everytime, generate the list of indices, shuffle it, and use it as a queue or a stack. In that way, the index you take is poped from that collection and so will not be chosen anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [use `random.sample(population, k)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) with a size that does not exceed your data:

```
# create the file
with open("tf.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""Ball
Rock
Pen""")
```

Then:

```
import random

with open("tf.txt","r") as f:
    lines = [ x.strip() for x in f]

for _ in range(5):
    print(random.sample(lines,k=len(lines)))
```

Output:

```
['Pen', 'Rock', 'Ball']
['Ball', 'Rock', 'Pen']
['Pen', 'Rock', 'Ball']
['Pen', 'Ball', 'Rock']
['Ball', 'Pen', 'Rock']
```

To get them on different lines:

```
print(*random.sample(lines,k=len(lines)),sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
Ball
Rock
Pen
```

---

If you always want the 3 outputs, you could as well simply [random.shuffle(..)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) your `lines` using:

```
import random

with open("tf.txt","r") as f:
    lines = [ x.strip() for x in f]

random.shuffle(lines) # inplace shuffling lines
print(*lines,"", sep="\n")
random.shuffle(lines)
print(*lines,"", sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
Ball
Rock
Pen

Rock
Ball
Pen
```

Sidenote: its better to cache the `len(lines)` in a variable if you use it multiple times - else it would have to be evaluated again and again.

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem, you gave a very simple answer compared to others.

Answer (score 1):

When you read your file do this instead:

```
with open("textfile.txt", "r") as f:
    words = [i.strip() for i in f.readlines()]
```

Using with statement ensures the file is properly closed after opening it. Your problem lies in: `line = lines[random.randint(0, 2)]` where you can get the same line twice. Reading all your lines to a list and using random.sample instead you make sure you won't get any duplicates.

Then you can use random.sample instead:

```
import random
random.seed(400)    # <-- makes sure we get same randomness
choice = random.sample(words, 3)
print('\n'.join(choice)) 

#Rock
#Pen
#Ball
```

Compare that with:

```
import random
random.seed(400)    # <-- makes sure we get same randomness
choice = random.choice(words)
print(choice)
choice = random.choice(words)
print(choice)
choice = random.choice(words)
print(choice)

#Pen
#Rock
#Rock
```

Comment: Any reason that the sample is the same each time I run the program? Any way I can change the order in which they print?

Comment: @jakethefake By providing a `random.seed()` you "fixate" the randomness - meaning you get the same sequence of random numbers if you do the same operations - just comment the line, and seed will be different for each rund and you'll get different random numbers drawn...

Answer (score -1):

Put your outputs in sets:
`myfirstset = set(choice)`

Then use the merging function:
`total = myssecondset.union(mysfirstset)`